# Category of (co)commutative Hopf monoids in an exact category

Tags: ct.category-theory, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, abelian-categories

I'm transferring this question over from SE, since it didn't get much attention over there.

Let $(C, \otimes)$ be an exact monoidal category, and let $H(C)$ be the category of cocommutative and commutative Hopf monoids in $C$ with respect to $\otimes$.

What can be said about this category? When is it abelian? If $H(C)$ is abelian, are there always enough projectives or injectives? This is true when $C= \operatorname{Vec}_k$, for some field $k$. Can this be generalized?

Note: As was mentioned in the comments in MSE by Qiaochu Yuan, if we take $\otimes$ to be the cartesian product then we just recover the category of abelian group objects, so in general $H(C)$ $\textit{won't}$ be abelian if $C$ is not exact.

Comment: Should you link to the MSE question?

Comment: Admittedly I don't know how links work. But it's posted almost verbatim here

Comment: Cross posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499042/category-of-cocommutative-hopf-monoids